# Kubuntu 14.04 hangs on logo while startup

Tags: ati, kubuntu, startup, logo

Today I installed the newest updates for my kubuntu 14.04 and after I restarted the system, it won't load properly. It hangs on the logo. I was in a hurry, so I didn't look, what I installed exactly. Might be the new kernel.

The exact state is: the logo flickers as it usually does, till the point, where it should disappear and the login screen appear. But it doesn't. It just stops flickering. But if I press the shutdown button on my PC, the logo starts flickering again. I tried booting up with the previous kernel-versions (3.13.0-24 - 3.13.0-34) and the same thing happens (with the 24 the logo disappears and I only see a black screen).

I have an ATI graphics card with 3 monitors. 
Intel Core i5
ASRock z77 pro3

I am a noob, so I don't know, how to restore my system to a last working state. Please help me with that.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as of today, after an upgrade and reboot.  I get stuck at a bright kubuntu logo.  I can access the various non-graphic login screens using Ctrl-alt-F1 etc.  I can boot if I select a much older kernel (3.2. something, as opposed to the default 3.13) but I expect this will create other problems.  /etc/syslog and boot.log don't show anything alarming.  I am not using ATI graphics (have nvidia, never caused a problem).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please do not type a "Me too" kind of comment as an answer. Either upvote the question, post a comment (when you have enough reputation) or ask your own question.